# Error: Could not find or load main class ( in Java 8)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, java-8, chromebook

I am trying to learn Java and I've made my first program and compiled it into a class file (the file is called `aye.java` and when compiled I have `aye.class`, I think the compilation worked). However when I use the `java` command in the folder where the class is located it just returns below error -

```
Could not find or load main class aye.class.
```

I have tried including the package name (com.java24hours) but it still doesn't work.. please help!

Commands I have tried:

```
java aye.class
java com.java24hours.aye.class
java aye
java com.java24hours.aye
```

program code:

```
   package com.java24hours;

    class aye {
            public static void main(String[] args)  {
                    //java code yeet
                    String aye = "Hello World!";
                    System.out.println(aye);
            }
    }
```

(I am running Linux on a Chromebook and have installed Java via the ppa:webupd8team/java)

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a classpath error. Make sure you're running the program from the root directory

Comment: What if you make the class public? `public class aya`

Comment: Also, try running java with the full path to your class: `java C:\path\aye`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wanna put binaries to `./bin` folder.

Compile aye.java:

```
javac -d ./bin aye.java
```

Then `cd` to `./bin` directory and run the program:

```
cd bin
java com.java24hours.aye
```

Answer (score 0):

well im stupid

since im new to java, i didn't know anything about packages and such. turns out all i had to do was put the class file in a folder named "ya" (that's the name of the package - i updated the program) and run the command

```
java -cp /home/ramsey/Documents/ya aye
```

(-cp stands for classpath, and you use it when you want to specify where you class is located MAKE SURE TO PUT IT IN A FOLDER NAMED AFTER YOUR PACKAGE!!!)

the wiki page is helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)
its under the section setting the path to execute java programs

thanks for the help everyone!